Can a job inspect its "deploy environment"?
GitHub Actions allows maintainers to require that a workflow job meet certain criteria before running, using the environments feature. For example, they may require that a job get explicit approval from two specific maintainers before running, guarantee the job only runs on specific branches or after a minimal time delay, etc.
A workflow job is set to run in a specific environment by setting its environment: variable:
jobs:
  deploy:
    environment: production  # requires approval by @foo and @bar
    steps:
      - ...

Note that this is entirely unrelated to ${{ github.env }}, which contains the existing environment variables.
Is there a workflow variable that can be used at runtime to inspect the environment's requirements, or at least its name?
I understand that we could use ${{ github.jobs.deploy.environment.name }} to get the environment's name in the example above, but I'm trying to find a solution that doesn't require hardcoding the job's name, so that it can be used within a GitHub Action:
jobs:
  deploy:
    environment: prod
    steps:
      # Run an Action to confirm that the environment
      # satisfies some constraints.
      # The Action therefore won't know the job's name,
      # unless we pass it as an argument, which doesn't
      # seem "elegant".
      - use: my/environment_checker@v1

I've seen there's a REST API endpoint to get the environment's description given a name, but I haven't found a way to identify the environment's name in the first place (other than checking out the repository and inspecting the workflow file itself, which seems like overkill).

I don't think it lives in any context, but you could set the value as a job-level environment variable, and then reference that both to set the job environment and when you want to know the value, similar to this example.
